# How do I enable Global Menus and fix HUD (after upgrading to 12.04 from 10.04)?

Tags: appmenu, hud

I upgraded from Ubuntu 10.04 LTS to 12.04 LTS. It's more or less working.

But, Global Menus aren't working, and when I use HUD no results ever appear. (Example: I search for "F" (without the quotes)) and nothing is found in any application (Terminal, Home Folder,...)

I already did:

```
sudo apt-get install appmenu-gtk appmenu-gtk3 appmenu-qt
```

Then restarted, but nothing.

Any ideas?

- I deleted ~/.config, ~/.gnome2, ~/.compiz-1, ~/.icons and a dozen other such directories (obviously not recommended, but whatever...), restarted, and still no change.
- I have a NVIDIA GeForce GT 430 and am using the "post release updates" provided by the Additional Drivers panel in System Settings. Maybe this is related?
- Uninstalled the drivers mentioned, rebooted using whatever vanilla detection scheme Ubuntu has going on, no change.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This happend to me aswell after upgrading to 12.04.

You should install [indicator-appmenu](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/indicator-appmenu) [image: Install indicator-appmenu] which wasn't installed on my system (or was removed by the installer). After this my global menu was working perfectly. (May require a log out and in or restart to connect.)

```
 sudo apt-get install indicator-appmenu
```

To immediately apply without re-login restart Unity: Open a terminal and issue:

```
unity --replace
```

Comment: This fixed the issue for me, too. **Be warned that `unity --replace` did crash for me. Logout and re-login fixed the issue.**