# HUD won't work on 12.04

Tags: unity, 12.04, appmenu, hud

I upgraded to 12.04 right after it was released, and once it installed, I was eager to try the new features. After fiddling around with most of them, I forgot to try the brand new HUD. I tapped the alt key... and nothing happened. I searched around to see if I disabled it, but I didn't. Also, holding alt still showed the appmenu at the top. Is there a reason that it isn't working on my computer?

Comment: Please can you look at this Q to see if your HUD key is set correctly - thanks http://askubuntu.com/questions/122209/how-do-i-modify-or-disable-the-huds-use-of-the-alt-key

Comment: It was. But thanks to you, I decided to change it to something different and then back, and I found out the problem (there was a conflict with the HUD and a compiz plug in)

Comment: There is a related bug entry in Launchpad: https://bugs.launchpad.net/bugs/995040

Answer (score 3):

I figured out that it wasn't working because of conflicts with the compiz scale plugin. Now it works!

Answer (score 3):

After an upgrade, from 10.04 to 12.04, the HUD did appear with Alt but whatever I typed there were no results. The solution was to type in a Terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install indicator-appmenu-tools
```

Then press <kbd>Enter</kbd>. It worked!

Comment: I did this and now I do see results when I type stuff in HUD, but the results seem to come from random places of other apps (not the currently active app) and the results don't even match what I have actually typed... Very weird, has anybody seen this?

Comment: Restarting the computer solved the problem. I think it's worth mentioning in the answer... Thanks anyway!

Comment: Why isn't this installed by default?

Answer (score 1):

Could reproduce the problem in a Unity 2D session. When logout and switching to normal Unity session the HUD worked. A [source](http://www.techlw.com/2012/03/install-hud-in-unity-2d-ubuntu-1204.html) says that HUD is not available in Unity 2D and suggests to add an ppa with enabled Unity 2D.

[How do I enable Global Menus and fix HUD (after upgrading to 12.04 from 10.04)?](https://askubuntu.com/q/126295/10475) suggests to install `indicator-appmenu`. I tried this solution and after a relogin (or `unity --replace` in a terminal) HUD was also working in Unity 2D.

There is an open bug report on this issue: https://bugs.launchpad.net/bugs/995040